Ubuntu 20.04 distro on WSL2 won't reboot after application heap errors and shutdown
I was running Ubuntu 20.04 distro on WSL2 Windows 11 for some weeks without issue. The VM is restricted to 8GB.
Today I saw some memory heap exhausted errors when doing a large npm install.
After a few of these application heap exhausted crashes, the bash terminal became non-responsive. I did a reboot of ubuntu, but could not restart it. Then a reboot of Windows.
wsl -list shows I have managed to restart the distro, but I cannot get a terminal.
I booted with safeMode in .wslconfig, and I see the below logged, but no obvious issues.
[    0.000000] Linux version 5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 (root@941d701f84f1) (gcc (GCC) 11.2.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.37) #1 SMP Fri Mar 29 23:14:13 UTC 2024
[    0.000000] Command line: initrd=\initrd.img WSL_ROOT_INIT=1 panic=-1 nr_cpus=2 hv_utils.timesync_implicit=1 console=ttyS0,115200 debug pty.legacy_count=0
[    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
[    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
[    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
[    0.000000]   Centaur CentaurHauls
[    0.000000] BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009ffff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000e0000-0x00000000000e0fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x00000000001fffff] ACPI data
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000200000-0x00000000f7ffffff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x0000000207ffffff] usable
[    0.000000] NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
[    0.000000] DMI not present or invalid.
[    0.000000] Hypervisor detected: Microsoft Hyper-V
[    0.000000] Hyper-V: privilege flags low 0xae7f, high 0x3b8030, hints 0xc2c, misc 0xe0bed7b2
[    0.000000] Hyper-V Host Build:22621-10.0-3-0.3880
[    0.000000] Hyper-V: Nested features: 0x0
[    0.000000] Hyper-V: LAPIC Timer Frequency: 0x1e8480
[    0.000000] Hyper-V: Using hypercall for remote TLB flush
[    0.000000] clocksource: hyperv_clocksource_tsc_page: mask: 0xffffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x24e6a1710, max_idle_ns: 440795202120 ns
[    0.000002] tsc: Detected 3792.647 MHz processor
[    0.000014] e820: update [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff] usable ==> reserved
[    0.000016] e820: remove [mem 0x000a0000-0x000fffff] usable
[    0.000018] last_pfn = 0x208000 max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
[    0.000051] x86/PAT: Configuration [0-7]: WB  WC  UC- UC  WB  WP  UC- WT
[    0.000065] last_pfn = 0xf8000 max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
[    0.000072] Using GB pages for direct mapping
[    0.000291] RAMDISK: [mem 0x03dda000-0x03fe1fff]
[    0.000294] ACPI: Early table checksum verification disabled
[    0.000297] ACPI: RSDP 0x00000000000E0000 000024 (v02 VRTUAL)
[    0.000301] ACPI: XSDT 0x0000000000100000 000044 (v01 VRTUAL MICROSFT 00000001 MSFT 00000001)
[    0.000306] ACPI: FACP 0x0000000000101000 000114 (v06 VRTUAL MICROSFT 00000001 MSFT 00000001)
[    0.000310] ACPI: DSDT 0x00000000001011B8 01E191 (v02 MSFTVM DSDT01   00000001 MSFT 05000000)
[    0.000313] ACPI: FACS 0x0000000000101114 000040
[    0.000314] ACPI: OEM0 0x0000000000101154 000064 (v01 VRTUAL MICROSFT 00000001 MSFT 00000001)
[    0.000316] ACPI: SRAT 0x000000000011F349 0002D0 (v02 VRTUAL MICROSFT 00000001 MSFT 00000001)
[    0.000318] ACPI: APIC 0x000000000011F619 000058 (v04 VRTUAL MICROSFT 00000001 MSFT 00000001)
[    0.000319] ACPI: Reserving FACP table memory at [mem 0x101000-0x101113]
[    0.000320] ACPI: Reserving DSDT table memory at [mem 0x1011b8-0x11f348]
[    0.000320] ACPI: Reserving FACS table memory at [mem 0x101114-0x101153]
[    0.000321] ACPI: Reserving OEM0 table memory at [mem 0x101154-0x1011b7]
[    0.000321] ACPI: Reserving SRAT table memory at [mem 0x11f349-0x11f618]
[    0.000322] ACPI: Reserving APIC table memory at [mem 0x11f619-0x11f670]
[    0.000445] Zone ranges:
[    0.000446]   DMA      [mem 0x0000000000001000-0x0000000000ffffff]
[    0.000448]   DMA32    [mem 0x0000000001000000-0x00000000ffffffff]
[    0.000449]   Normal   [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x0000000207ffffff]
[    0.000450]   Device   empty
[    0.000450] Movable zone start for each node
[    0.000451] Early memory node ranges
[    0.000452]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000000001000-0x000000000009ffff]
[    0.000453]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000000200000-0x00000000f7ffffff]
[    0.000454]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x0000000207ffffff]
[    0.000455] Initmem setup node 0 [mem 0x0000000000001000-0x0000000207ffffff]
[    0.000545] On node 0, zone DMA: 1 pages in unavailable ranges
[    0.000576] On node 0, zone DMA: 352 pages in unavailable ranges
[    0.007147] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x01] dfl dfl lint[0x1])
[    0.007387] IOAPIC[0]: apic_id 2, version 17, address 0xfec00000, GSI 0-23
[    0.007391] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 9 global_irq 9 high level)
[    0.007394] ACPI: Using ACPI (MADT) for SMP configuration information
[    0.007400] smpboot: Allowing 2 CPUs, 0 hotplug CPUs
[    0.007409] [mem 0xf8000000-0xffffffff] available for PCI devices
[    0.007410] Booting paravirtualized kernel on Hyper-V
[    0.007411] clocksource: refined-jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 19112604462750000 ns
[    0.010709] setup_percpu: NR_CPUS:256 nr_cpumask_bits:256 nr_cpu_ids:2 nr_node_ids:1
[    0.010893] percpu: Embedded 54 pages/cpu s180696 r8192 d32296 u1048576
[    0.010897] pcpu-alloc: s180696 r8192 d32296 u1048576 alloc=1*2097152
[    0.010899] pcpu-alloc: [0] 0 1
[    0.010907] Hyper-V: PV spinlocks enabled
[    0.010908] PV qspinlock hash table entries: 256 (order: 0, 4096 bytes, linear)
[    0.010912] Built 1 zonelists, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 2063365
[    0.010913] Kernel command line: initrd=\initrd.img WSL_ROOT_INIT=1 panic=-1 nr_cpus=2 hv_utils.timesync_implicit=1 console=ttyS0,115200 debug pty.legacy_count=0
[    0.010962] Unknown kernel command line parameters "WSL_ROOT_INIT=1", will be passed to user space.
[    0.011404] Dentry cache hash table entries: 1048576 (order: 11, 8388608 bytes, linear)
[    0.011659] Inode-cache hash table entries: 524288 (order: 10, 4194304 bytes, linear)
[    0.011684] mem auto-init: stack:off, heap alloc:off, heap free:off
[    0.021701] Memory: 4081320K/8387196K available (18452K kernel code, 2628K rwdata, 9648K rodata, 2008K init, 1816K bss, 255928K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
[    0.021728] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=2, Nodes=1
[    0.021739] ftrace: allocating 52916 entries in 207 pages
[    0.038316] ftrace: allocated 207 pages with 6 groups
[    0.038454] rcu: Hierarchical RCU implementation.
[    0.038456] rcu:     RCU restricting CPUs from NR_CPUS=256 to nr_cpu_ids=2.
[    0.038457]  Rude variant of Tasks RCU enabled.
[    0.038457]  Tracing variant of Tasks RCU enabled.
[    0.038458] rcu: RCU calculated value of scheduler-enlistment delay is 10 jiffies.
[    0.038459] rcu: Adjusting geometry for rcu_fanout_leaf=16, nr_cpu_ids=2
[    0.041265] Using NULL legacy PIC
[    0.041267] NR_IRQS: 16640, nr_irqs: 440, preallocated irqs: 0
[    0.041663] random: crng init done
[    0.041683] Console: colour dummy device 80x25
[    0.161563] printk: console [ttyS0] enabled
[    0.162443] ACPI: Core revision 20210730
[    0.163585] Failed to register legacy timer interrupt
[    0.164601] APIC: Switch to symmetric I/O mode setup
[    0.165623] Hyper-V: Using IPI hypercalls
[    0.166438] Hyper-V: Using enlightened APIC (xapic mode)
[    0.166520] clocksource: tsc-early: mask: 0xffffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x6d566e81ef8, max_idle_ns: 881591114352 ns
[    0.169874] Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 7585.29 BogoMIPS (lpj=37926470)
[    0.172138] x86/cpu: User Mode Instruction Prevention (UMIP) activated
[    0.173496] Last level iTLB entries: 4KB 512, 2MB 512, 4MB 256
[    0.174712] Last level dTLB entries: 4KB 2048, 2MB 2048, 4MB 1024, 1GB 0
[    0.176666] Spectre V1 : Mitigation: usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
[    0.178429] Spectre V2 : Mitigation: Retpolines
[    0.179361] Spectre V2 : Spectre v2 / SpectreRSB mitigation: Filling RSB on context switch
[    0.179865] Spectre V2 : Spectre v2 / SpectreRSB : Filling RSB on VMEXIT
[    0.179865] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.179865] Spectre V2 : mitigation: Enabling conditional Indirect Branch Prediction Barrier
[    0.179865] Spectre V2 : User space: Mitigation: STIBP via seccomp and prctl
[    0.179865] Speculative Store Bypass: Mitigation: Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl and seccomp
[    0.179865] Speculative Return Stack Overflow: IBPB-extending microcode not applied!
[    0.179865] Speculative Return Stack Overflow: WARNING: See https://kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/srso.html for mitigation options.
[    0.179865] Speculative Return Stack Overflow: Mitigation: safe RET, no microcode
[    0.179865] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x001: 'x87 floating point registers'
[    0.179865] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x002: 'SSE registers'
[    0.179865] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x004: 'AVX registers'
[    0.179865] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x020: 'AVX-512 opmask'
[    0.179865] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x040: 'AVX-512 Hi256'
[    0.179865] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x080: 'AVX-512 ZMM_Hi256'
[    0.179865] x86/fpu: xstate_offset[2]:  576, xstate_sizes[2]:  256
[    0.179865] x86/fpu: xstate_offset[5]:  832, xstate_sizes[5]:   64
[    0.179865] x86/fpu: xstate_offset[6]:  896, xstate_sizes[6]:  512
[    0.179865] x86/fpu: xstate_offset[7]: 1408, xstate_sizes[7]: 1024
[    0.179865] x86/fpu: Enabled xstate features 0xe7, context size is 2432 bytes, using 'compacted' format.
[    0.179865] Freeing SMP alternatives memory: 60K
[    0.179865] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.179865] LSM: Security Framework initializing
[    0.179865] landlock: Up and running.
[    0.179865] Mount-cache hash table entries: 16384 (order: 5, 131072 bytes, linear)
[    0.179865] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 16384 (order: 5, 131072 bytes, linear)
[    0.179865] smpboot: CPU0: AMD Ryzen 7 7840HS with Radeon 780M Graphics (family: 0x19, model: 0x74, stepping: 0x1)
[    0.179865] Performance Events: PMU not available due to virtualization, using software events only.
[    0.179865] signal: max sigframe size: 3376
[    0.179865] rcu: Hierarchical SRCU implementation.
[    0.179865] smp: Bringing up secondary CPUs ...
[    0.179865] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
[    0.179865] .... node  #0, CPUs:      #1
[    0.179865] smp: Brought up 1 node, 2 CPUs
[    0.179870] smpboot: Max logical packages: 1
[    0.180725] smpboot: Total of 2 processors activated (15170.58 BogoMIPS)
[    0.190226] node 0 deferred pages initialised in 10ms
[    0.191059] devtmpfs: initialized
[    0.191059] x86/mm: Memory block size: 128MB
[    0.191955] clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 19112604462750000 ns
[    0.191955] futex hash table entries: 512 (order: 3, 32768 bytes, linear)
[    0.191955] NET: Registered PF_NETLINK/PF_ROUTE protocol family
[    0.191955] audit: initializing netlink subsys (disabled)
[    0.199896] audit: type=2000 audit(1722511740.030:1): state=initialized audit_enabled=0 res=1
[    0.199950] thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'step_wise'
[    0.201605] cpuidle: using governor menu
[    0.201955] ACPI: bus type PCI registered
[    0.201955] PCI: Fatal: No config space access function found
[    0.201955] kprobes: kprobe jump-optimization is enabled. All kprobes are optimized if possible.
[    0.209902] HugeTLB registered 1.00 GiB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
[    0.211215] HugeTLB registered 2.00 MiB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
[    0.212577] raid6: skip pq benchmark and using algorithm avx512x4
[    0.212577] raid6: using avx512x2 recovery algorithm
[    0.212577] ACPI: Added _OSI(Module Device)
[    0.212934] ACPI: Added _OSI(Processor Device)
[    0.212934] ACPI: Added _OSI(3.0 _SCP Extensions)
[    0.212934] ACPI: Added _OSI(Processor Aggregator Device)
[    0.212934] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Dell-Video)
[    0.213251] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
[    0.214312] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-HPI-Hybrid-Graphics)
[    0.222369] ACPI: 1 ACPI AML tables successfully acquired and loaded
[    0.229955] ACPI: Interpreter enabled
[    0.230732] ACPI: PM: (supports S0 S5)
[    0.231504] ACPI: Using IOAPIC for interrupt routing
[    0.232549] PCI: Using host bridge windows from ACPI; if necessary, use "pci=nocrs" and report a bug
[    0.234520] ACPI: Enabled 2 GPEs in block 00 to 0F
[    0.236390] iommu: Default domain type: Translated
[    0.239894] iommu: DMA domain TLB invalidation policy: lazy mode
[    0.241181] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    0.241952] ACPI: bus type USB registered
[    0.242770] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.243847] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.244897] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.245905] pps_core: LinuxPPS API ver. 1 registered
[    0.246895] pps_core: Software ver. 5.3.6 - Copyright 2005-2007 Rodolfo Giometti <giometti@linux.it>
[    0.248682] PTP clock support registered
[    0.249868] hv_vmbus: Vmbus version:5.3
[    0.250776] PCI: Using ACPI for IRQ routing
[    0.249927] hv_vmbus: Unknown GUID: c376c1c3-d276-48d2-90a9-c04748072c60
[    0.251658] PCI: System does not support PCI
[    0.253985] clocksource: Switched to clocksource tsc-early
[    0.264041] VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.6.0
[    0.264882] VFS: Dquot-cache hash table entries: 512 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.266249] FS-Cache: Loaded
[    0.266856] pnp: PnP ACPI init
[    0.267633] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 3 devices
[    0.269133] NET: Registered PF_INET protocol family
[    0.270247] IP idents hash table entries: 131072 (order: 8, 1048576 bytes, linear)
[    0.272105] tcp_listen_portaddr_hash hash table entries: 4096 (order: 4, 65536 bytes, linear)
[    0.273793] Table-perturb hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes, linear)
[    0.275306] TCP established hash table entries: 65536 (order: 7, 524288 bytes, linear)
[    0.276874] TCP bind hash table entries: 65536 (order: 8, 1048576 bytes, linear)
[    0.278456] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 65536 bind 65536)
[    0.280110] UDP hash table entries: 4096 (order: 5, 131072 bytes, linear)
[    0.281462] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 4096 (order: 5, 131072 bytes, linear)
[    0.282918] NET: Registered PF_UNIX/PF_LOCAL protocol family
[    0.288580] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
[    0.290056] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
[    0.291026] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
[    0.291986] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
[    0.293269] PCI: CLS 0 bytes, default 64
[    0.294060] PCI-DMA: Using software bounce buffering for IO (SWIOTLB)
[    0.295426] software IO TLB: mapped [mem 0x00000000f4000000-0x00000000f8000000] (64MB)
[    0.297050] kvm: no hardware support
[    0.297778] has_svm: svm not available
[    0.298541] kvm: no hardware support
[    0.299538] Initialise system trusted keyrings
[    0.300469] workingset: timestamp_bits=46 max_order=21 bucket_order=0
[    0.302745] squashfs: version 4.0 (2009/01/31) Phillip Lougher
[    0.304010] NFS: Registering the id_resolver key type
[    0.305028] Key type id_resolver registered
[    0.305873] Key type id_legacy registered
[    0.306684] nfs4filelayout_init: NFSv4 File Layout Driver Registering...
[    0.307994] nfs4flexfilelayout_init: NFSv4 Flexfile Layout Driver Registering...
[    0.308938] Trying to unpack rootfs image as initramfs...
[    0.309497] Installing knfsd (copyright (C) 1996 okir@monad.swb.de).
[    0.312127] Freeing initrd memory: 2080K
[    0.313021] Key type cifs.idmap registered
[    0.313884] fuse: init (API version 7.34)
[    0.314763] SGI XFS with ACLs, security attributes, realtime, scrub, repair, quota, no debug enabled
[    0.316784] 9p: Installing v9fs 9p2000 file system support
[    0.317896] FS-Cache: Netfs '9p' registered for caching
[    0.319041] FS-Cache: Netfs 'ceph' registered for caching
[    0.320166] ceph: loaded (mds proto 32)
[    0.323561] NET: Registered PF_ALG protocol family
[    0.324574] xor: automatically using best checksumming function   avx
[    0.325987] Key type asymmetric registered
[    0.327209] Asymmetric key parser 'x509' registered
[    0.328434] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 248)
[    0.330256] hv_vmbus: registering driver hv_pci
[    0.331799] ACPI: AC: AC Adapter [AC1] (on-line)
[    0.333200] ACPI: battery: Slot [BAT1] (battery present)
[    0.334332] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 4 ports, IRQ sharing disabled
[    0.335781] 00:00: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
[    0.337424] 00:01: ttyS1 at I/O 0x2f8 (irq = 3, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
[    0.339014] Non-volatile memory driver v1.3
[    0.339951] [drm] Initialized vgem 1.0.0 20120112 for vgem on minor 0
[    0.343124] brd: module loaded
[    0.344192] loop: module loaded
[    0.344884] hv_vmbus: registering driver hv_storvsc
[    0.345928] wireguard: WireGuard 1.0.0 loaded. See www.wireguard.com for information.
[    0.347473] wireguard: Copyright (C) 2015-2019 Jason A. Donenfeld <Jason@zx2c4.com>. All Rights Reserved.
[    0.349463] tun: Universal TUN/TAP device driver, 1.6
[    0.350655] PPP generic driver version 2.4.2
[    0.351602] PPP BSD Compression module registered
[    0.352563] PPP Deflate Compression module registered
[    0.353602] PPP MPPE Compression module registered
[    0.354597] NET: Registered PF_PPPOX protocol family
[    0.355671] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ether
[    0.356840] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ncm
[    0.358038] usbcore: registered new interface driver r8153_ecm
[    0.359349] hv_vmbus: registering driver hv_netvsc
[    0.360452] scsi host0: storvsc_host_t
[    0.360462] VFIO - User Level meta-driver version: 0.3
[    0.362653] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_acm
[    0.363778] cdc_acm: USB Abstract Control Model driver for USB modems and ISDN adapters
[    0.365413] vhci_hcd vhci_hcd.0: USB/IP Virtual Host Controller
[    0.366594] vhci_hcd vhci_hcd.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    0.368018] vhci_hcd: created sysfs vhci_hcd.0
[    0.368961] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 5.15
[    0.370589] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    0.372031] usb usb1: Product: USB/IP Virtual Host Controller
[    0.373206] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 vhci_hcd
[    0.374862] usb usb1: SerialNumber: vhci_hcd.0
[    0.375869] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.376657] hub 1-0:1.0: 8 ports detected
[    0.378039] vhci_hcd vhci_hcd.0: USB/IP Virtual Host Controller
[    0.379280] vhci_hcd vhci_hcd.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    0.380780] usb usb2: We don't know the algorithms for LPM for this host, disabling LPM.
[    0.382429] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003, bcdDevice= 5.15
[    0.384071] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    0.385524] usb usb2: Product: USB/IP Virtual Host Controller
[    0.386714] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 vhci_hcd
[    0.388360] usb usb2: SerialNumber: vhci_hcd.0
[    0.389429] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.390241] hub 2-0:1.0: 8 ports detected
[    0.391219] hv_vmbus: registering driver hyperv_keyboard
[    0.392342] rtc_cmos 00:02: RTC can wake from S4
[    0.394221] rtc_cmos 00:02: registered as rtc0
[    0.395312] rtc_cmos 00:02: setting system clock to 2024-08-01T11:29:00 UTC (1722511740)
[    0.396973] rtc_cmos 00:02: alarms up to one month, 114 bytes nvram
[    0.398367] device-mapper: ioctl: 4.45.0-ioctl (2021-03-22) initialised: dm-devel@redhat.com
[    0.400147] device-mapper: raid: Loading target version 1.15.1
[    0.401370] hid: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[    0.402432] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    0.403544] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    0.404392] hv_utils: Registering HyperV Utility Driver
[    0.405492] hv_vmbus: registering driver hv_utils
[    0.406493] hv_vmbus: registering driver hv_balloon
[    0.406859] hv_utils: TimeSync IC version 4.0
[    0.408339] hv_vmbus: registering driver dxgkrnl
[    0.408482] hv_balloon: Using Dynamic Memory protocol version 2.0
[    0.409323] drop_monitor: Initializing network drop monitor service
[    0.411779] Free page reporting enabled
[    0.411790] Mirror/redirect action on
[    0.412538] hv_balloon: Cold memory discard hint enabled with order 9
[    0.413285] u32 classifier
[    0.415089]     Performance counters on
[    0.415853]     input device check on
[    0.416576]     Actions configured
[    0.417735] IPVS: Registered protocols (TCP, UDP)
[    0.418715] IPVS: Connection hash table configured (size=4096, memory=32Kbytes)
[    0.420236] IPVS: ipvs loaded.
[    0.420851] IPVS: [rr] scheduler registered.
[    0.421911] IPVS: [wrr] scheduler registered.
[    0.422980] IPVS: [sh] scheduler registered.
[    0.423880] ipt_CLUSTERIP: ClusterIP Version 0.8 loaded successfully
[    0.425145] Initializing XFRM netlink socket
[    0.426057] NET: Registered PF_INET6 protocol family
[    0.427335] Segment Routing with IPv6
[    0.428092] In-situ OAM (IOAM) with IPv6
[    0.428926] NET: Registered PF_PACKET protocol family
[    0.429961] Bridge firewalling registered
[    0.430785] 8021q: 802.1Q VLAN Support v1.8
[    0.431649] sctp: Hash tables configured (bind 256/256)
[    0.432746] 9pnet: Installing 9P2000 support
[    0.433622] Key type dns_resolver registered
[    0.434481] Key type ceph registered
[    0.435300] libceph: loaded (mon/osd proto 15/24)
[    0.436283] NET: Registered PF_VSOCK protocol family
[    0.437304] hv_vmbus: registering driver hv_sock
[    0.438281] IPI shorthand broadcast: enabled
[    0.439159] sched_clock: Marking stable (310720564, 128407700)->(509761700, -70633436)
[    0.440838] registered taskstats version 1
[    0.441738] Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates
[    0.443075] Btrfs loaded, crc32c=crc32c-generic, zoned=no, fsverity=no
[    0.445436] Freeing unused kernel image (initmem) memory: 2008K
[    0.446622] Write protecting the kernel read-only data: 30720k
[    0.448139] Freeing unused kernel image (text/rodata gap) memory: 2024K
[    0.449595] Freeing unused kernel image (rodata/data gap) memory: 592K
[    0.450894] Run /init as init process
[    0.451653]   with arguments:
[    0.452280]     /init
[    0.452769]   with environment:
[    0.453514]     HOME=/
[    0.454023]     TERM=linux
[    0.454600]     WSL_ROOT_INIT=1
[    0.460256] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Msft     Virtual Disk     1.0  PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    0.460270] WSL (1) WARNING: SAFE MODE ENABLED - many features will be disabled
[    0.464177] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[    0.465575] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 795856 512-byte logical blocks: (407 MB/389 MiB)
[    0.467099] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is on
[    0.468066] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 0f 00 80 00
[    0.469252] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    0.472423] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[    0.476118] EXT4-fs (sda): mounted filesystem without journal. Opts: (null). Quota mode: none.
GNS: Processing Next Message
GNS: Received empty message, exiting
GnsEngine exiting
StartGns returning 0 (GNS Socket 7, MessageType 0)
[    0.528931] scsi 0:0:0:1: Direct-Access     Msft     Virtual Disk     1.0  PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    0.533622] sd 0:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[    0.534157] sd 0:0:0:1: [sdb] 2147483648 512-byte logical blocks: (1.10 TB/1.00 TiB)
[    0.536866] sd 0:0:0:1: [sdb] 4096-byte physical blocks
[    0.537950] sd 0:0:0:1: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[    0.539130] sd 0:0:0:1: [sdb] Mode Sense: 0f 00 00 00
[    0.540204] sd 0:0:0:1: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    0.544007] sd 0:0:0:1: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[    0.554313] EXT4-fs (sdb): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: discard,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered. Quota mode: none.
[    0.562761] WSL (1) WARNING: SAFE MODE ENABLED - automount.enabled disabled
[    0.564199] WSL (1) WARNING: SAFE MODE ENABLED - automount.ldconfig disabled
[    0.565581] WSL (1) WARNING: SAFE MODE ENABLED - automount.mountFsTab disabled
[    0.567065] WSL (1) WARNING: SAFE MODE ENABLED - boot.systemd disabled
[    0.568349] WSL (1) WARNING: SAFE MODE ENABLED - network.generateHosts disabled
[    0.569838] WSL (1) WARNING: SAFE MODE ENABLED - network.generateResolvConf disabled
[    0.571373] WSL (1) WARNING: SAFE MODE ENABLED - fileServer.enabled disabled
[    0.572772] WSL (1) WARNING: SAFE MODE ENABLED - gpu.appendLibPath disabled
[    0.574148] WSL (1) WARNING: SAFE MODE ENABLED - gpu.enabled disabled
[    0.575429] WSL (1) WARNING: SAFE MODE ENABLED - interop.appendWindowsPath disabled
[    0.576948] WSL (1) WARNING: SAFE MODE ENABLED - interop.enabled disabled
[    0.578286] WSL (1) WARNING: SAFE MODE ENABLED - time.useWindowsTimezone disabled
[    0.663005] WSL (1) WARNING: /etc/resolv.conf updating disabled in /etc/wsl.conf
[    0.672496] WSL (1) WARNING: /etc/hosts updating disabled in /etc/wsl.conf
[    0.676042] WSL (1) WARNING: /etc/resolv.conf updating disabled in /etc/wsl.conf
[    1.368554] clocksource: tsc: mask: 0xffffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x6d566e81ef8, max_idle_ns: 881591114352 ns
[    1.371140] clocksource: Switched to clocksource tsc
[   49.263223] hv_balloon: Max. dynamic memory size: 8192 MB
[  600.474773] mini_init (103): drop_caches: 1
[ 4078.591608] WSL (1) WARNING: /etc/resolv.conf updating disabled in /etc/wsl.conf

Then nothing more.
I have tried wsl --shutdown as well. Also wsl export worked.
Anything I can do restore my distro?

I removed a  command in .bashrc to Load Angular CLI autocompletion:
source <(ng completion script).
ng was not installed causing an error so no prompt.
